# wix remove old but not install new version

Tags: wix, version

I can find what the problem is. Wix finds new version, removes old but not install new. What can be the problem?

log

```
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:32:53]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:32:53]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: NetFx40Redist
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:32:53]i201: Planned package: NetFx40Redist, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:32:53]i201: Planned package: Synchronizer, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:32:53]i207: Planned related bundle: {7d6ed5aa-7d5e-4ae7-821a-11a2299402c1}, type: Upgrade, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, dependency: None
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:32:53]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:32:53]i300: Apply begin
[0CB8:078C][2014-12-01T01:32:53]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0CB8:078C][2014-12-01T01:33:12]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0CB8:078C][2014-12-01T01:33:12]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\{d345c5a3-17e8-4106-a8e6-c89c587c52e1}\.be\InstallerBundle.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{d345c5a3-17e8-4106-a8e6-c89c587c52e1}\InstallerBundle.exe'
[0CB8:078C][2014-12-01T01:33:12]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {d345c5a3-17e8-4106-a8e6-c89c587c52e1}, version: 1.0.5.51
[0CB8:078C][2014-12-01T01:33:12]i301: Applying execute package: {7d6ed5aa-7d5e-4ae7-821a-11a2299402c1}, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7d6ed5aa-7d5e-4ae7-821a-11a2299402c1}\InstallerBundle.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7d6ed5aa-7d5e-4ae7-821a-11a2299402c1}\InstallerBundle.exe" -uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade -burn.ancestors={d345c5a3-17e8-4106-a8e6-c89c587c52e1}'
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:33:24]i319: Applied execute package: {7d6ed5aa-7d5e-4ae7-821a-11a2299402c1}, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:33:24]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[0A3C:0A40][2014-12-01T01:35:27]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
```

my product.wxs (part of upgrading)

```
    <Property Id='PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED' Secure='yes' />
    <Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
        <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes"
          Minimum="1.0.0.0"
                        Maximum='99.0.0.0'
                        IncludeMinimum="yes"
                        IncludeMaximum="no"
                        Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED"
                        IgnoreRemoveFailure="yes" />
    </Upgrade>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

What can cause this? Also, I should say that I have read questions about majorUpgrade and tried to add it but nothing changes. Moreover, this installer worked fine before last merge (but nothing is changed in installer). This is really frustrating.

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on here. Your upgrade element has OnlyDetect=yes, which means it will not upgrade anything, and you say that nothing was installed, so the MSI upgrade info is irrelevant. So it looks like your bundle is somehow set to do only an uninstall for some reason.

Comment: @PhilDW What additional information can I provide you with to define what wrong is? Bundle? I have read tons of information and haven't seen any concerns setting to do only uninstall. Disappointing thing...

Comment: I changed OnlyDetect=no and it works fine. Thank you for prompt.